# move Angular project to sub dir of express app

Tags: angular, express

I want to serve my static pages separate from my angular app - basically, I have a members area that is my angular app... and a whole lot of static html...

So I have my express routing like this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'members')));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public/index.html'));
})
app.get('/members/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'members/index.html'));
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Started on port ' + port);
})
```

I run 
    ng build --prod --aot --base-href /members/

I rename my dist folder to 'members'

And now I get 404s for all the bundles files such as

```
GET http://localhost:3002/members/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong? the file IS in that path....

the dir structure looks like this

```
app.js 
  /public
     |-- index.html
  /members
     |-- index.html
     |-- inline...bundle.js
     |-- main...bundle.js
     |-- polyfills...bundle.js
     |-- styles...bundle.css
```

Comment: try `ng build -prod --base-href /members --deploy-url /public`

Comment: I did it w/o the deploy-url - and it seems to have worked. the build process puts <base href="C:/dir/@git/members/" > - I don't know why it's putting a full path there - but making it <base href="/members/" > solves the last problem... so changing --base-href /members/ (my cmd) to --base-href /members (your suggestion) worked - I'll test more - I also changed my angular-cli.json  "outDir": "../members". THX

Comment: Great! seems like ends with `/` they put the hole path because its a directory or something. Good to know

Comment: If you make an answer - I'll mark as answer and upvote

Comment: Will do it thanks. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to `ng build -prod --base-href /members`.

For some reason we don't know yet, the `/` in the end indicates the angular to place the whole path of your project.